# Some Text Does not appear untill i Inspect Element in google chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, sitefinity

I developed an application on sitefinity(asp.net) when I ran it then some of it's elements like button text and labels are not loaded but when I inspect element it works properly.

This problem is just in Google chrome browser. 
What could be a reason ???

Google Chrome Update problem or some designing problem in my application.

Comment: Your code would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

It happens with me too in chrome as sitefinity create cache for every page and some time we are not able to see changes due to cache.

When you are going to make any change please set "No caching" option for page from title and properties option and once you done changes and test all then again reset it for caching option.

If this is not the reason then we need to look into code that you have done.